# how to find rows of Gridview whose textbox value is 1 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are total 600 rows in my gridview out of which there are 100 rows who are having 0 as a value of one of the textbox.

So I want list of all that rows whose textbox value is 0 using jquery

Comment: you'll need to show the code that you have attempted so far and the html to which it relates

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use jquery something like

```
$('gridview tr').each(function(){
  if(this+' input[type=text]').val() == 0){
      $('.rowlist').append($(this));  
  }
})
```

Comment: I got all the rows of the gridview. Code which i use:              $('[id$="grdView"] tbody tr').each(function(){
  if(($(this).find('input[id$="hfreason"]').val() == 0) && ($(this).find('input[id$="txtcreditamt"]').val()==0.00 || $(this).find('input[id$="txtcreditamt"]').val()==0)){
      $('.rowlist').append($(this));  
  }
});

Comment: This code returns me all the rows of Gridview. why so?

Comment: please provide me your url or fiddle link so i can review it